# Posting user_generated photo from new native Share Dialog in FacebookSDK on android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm, trying to post an image to the Facebook (with OpenGraph) using new SDK v3.5 Share Dialog described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/)

As a result I'm getting `com.facebook.FacebookException: Error retrieving image attachment.`

The image is added to the dialog like described in the documentation:

```
List<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
bitmaps.add(bitmap);

FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(ShareAwardActivity.this, action, "my_app:my_action", "my_object")
  .setImageAttachmentsForObject("my_object", bitmaps, true)
  .build();
facebookHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

It looks like SDK stores image in the cache folder to be read by Facebook app, but Facebook app can't read or upload it somehow.

I tried setImageAttachmentsForAction - didn't help.

Also tried to add the image url to my_object - it doesn't respect the user_generated flag

Does anyone succeeded in doing this?

Comment: Did you add a NativeAppCallContentProvider{YOUR_APP_ID} to your AndroidManifest? See the detailed javadocs for the setImageAttachmentsForObject method - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder#setImageAttachmentsForObject(String, List) as well as the NativeAppCallContentProvider class - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/NativeAppCallContentProvider/

Comment: Thank you, missed that. But now I'm getting in the log: BlueServiceQueue: Exception during service
        com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: (#324) Attached image (fbstaging://graph.facebook.com/staging_resources/MDExNDEzMTIyMzkyMjM0MTgwOjEzNjkzMTQzMDI=) failed to upload

Comment: That could be a temporary issue, are you consistently seeing it?

Comment: Ok, I added android:exported="true" for the provider in the manifest and now getting the following error: BlueServiceQueue: Exception during service
        org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error
        {"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"Application with ID ******324 has not been granted the capability to use the property fb:explicitly_shared.","code":1611165}}
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:208)

Comment: When I use it without **fb:explicitly_shared** and setImageAttachmentsForObject("myobject", bitmaps, **true**) it works, but the image is small in the timeline, not like user generated.

Comment: You should not set fb:explicitly_shared when going through the share dialog (it will magically do it for you). If you set it explicitly, then you must get your OG action approved for it. As for your image being user_generated, the best way to check if it worked or not is to see if the image appears in your app's photo album for the user. Depending on how big the image is, and potentially rendering issues, there could be different renderings of the story in timeline/newsfeed.

Comment: I set user_generated flag to true and use test users for testing, but I am having the same problem - photo is still very small. I wonder if it is because the action is not approved by facebook?

see my other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045839/user-generated-and-explicitly-shared-flag-does-not-work-when-publishing-actions