# Attach image in share dialog facebook android

Tags: android, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, dialog

Please help me with my problem.My application has a button share that calls the Facebook Dialog Share class and I want to attached image when I click the share button.

But when following the Facebook.Sharedialog documentation, it has a method called addImageAttachment(String, File) to attach images but when using code below, I cannot access the addImageAttachment method.

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                .setPicture("test.jpg") 
                .build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

Or, maybe if theres a better way in sharing images in facebook just like in a game application with a share button and shared the screenshot of you app.

thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in setPicture() you need to set a url for the image that you want to share.

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
            .setPicture("http://yourdomain.com/images/test.jpg") 
            .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

i see

try with this

```
 Bitmap bmp = R.drawable."bitmapFileName";
```

to take your bitmap from a drawable folder and...

```
protected Builder addImageAttachment(String imageName, Bitmap bitmap)
```

Comment: oh i see, but how about I want to share image from by assets folder?. and also in the facebook documentation they included an addImageAttachment(String,File) method. And it seems like to be used for local storage. i guess?

Comment: and how would i call the addImageAttachement method to link in my shareDialog?

Comment: `List<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
bitmaps.add(bitmap);

FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(ShareAwardActivity.this, action, "my_app:my_action", "my_object")
  .setImageAttachmentsForObject("my_object", bitmaps, true)
  .build();
facebookHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());`

Here is another post with your same problem 
[Attach images facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496508/posting-user-generated-photo-from-new-native-share-dialog-in-facebooksdk-on-andr)

Comment: Thanks for this @UrielUVD, but i need some help on this. what type of variable is the action? i cannot create that variable unless i know the type.thanks